# Elasticsearch Highlight result missing string

Tags: python-3.x, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to use Elasticsearch's highlighting feature to highlight certain words from a text field. The text can be short or long (over 300 chars sometimes). Here is the highlight field passed to search function:

```
def search(self):
    highlight = {
        "fields": {
            "content": {
                "type": "plain",
                "number_of_fragments": 0,
            }
        }
    }
    s = super(FacetedCustomSearch, self).search()
    return s.extra(highlight=highlight)
```

As you can see below, the highlighted text is missing the  `- 1 POUND BAG` string at the end. This usually happens when the text is over ~100 chars and sometimes with special characters like `!` or `/` or `-`

**content:** `YOUR OFFICEKITCHEN - TASTING KITCHEN - SWEET CHILI HABANERO - GOURMET HANDMADE CRAFT MEAT SNACK - 1 POUND BAG`

**highlighted content:** `YOUR OFFICEKITCHEN - TASTING KITCHEN - SWEET CHILI HABANERO - <em>GOURMET HAND</em><em>MA</em>DE CRAFT MEAT SNACK`

So far, I have tried to tweak the `number_of_fragments` (setting it to 0) and `fragment_size` and set the `type` to `plain`. Nothing seems to fix this issue. Any suggestions?

Using **elasticsearch-dsl 7.4.0**

Comment: answer sent please check

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the [fragment_size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html#control-highlighted-frags) more.

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_highlight", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "content" : "YOUR OFFICEKITCHEN - TASTING KITCHEN - SWEET CHILI HABANERO - GOURMET HANDMADE CRAFT MEAT SNACK - 1 POUND BAG" }
```

---

```
GET test_highlight/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "GOURMET HAND"
    }
  }, 
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 150
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]